# HashMap iteration complexity

Tags: java, hashmap, time-complexity

From java doc I know that:

> Iteration over collection views requires time proportional to the
>   "capacity" of the HashMap instance (the number of buckets) plus its
>   size (the number of key-value mappings). Thus, it's very important not
>   to set the initial capacity too high (or the load factor too low) if
>   iteration performance is important.

Does it mean the time complexity for iteration over HashMap is **O**(n²)? This question may sound silly but I'm actually a bit confused.

Answer (score 9):

No, this does not mean that the iteration complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

When the capacity `c` is set automatically, it grows as O(n) with the number of items, not as O(n<sup>2</sup>) of the items. According to source code, target capacity is computed as follows:

```
int targetCapacity = (int)(numKeysToBeAdded / loadFactor + 1);
```

where `loadFactor` is a `float` value set to `0.75f` by default.

The paragraph that you quote becomes relevant only when you set the capacity manually. It is telling you that the performance is O(c), not O(n), where `c` is the capacity that you set or the capacity computed automatically.

Answer (score 4):

No, it means that the complexity for iteration over a `HashMap` is O(n + s), where *n* is the number of mappings and *s* is the size.  It must iterate linearly over all *s* buckets and linearly over all *n* entries.